# How can i pass data of clicked row from one component to another component without passing to the url

Tags: angular

I have a mat table. onclick of any row i am able to console all the information of that row like this:

```
{
sid: "105", 
vid: "2", 
serviceName: "Chicken Tikka",
serviceDescription: "Non Veg Dish", 
createdOn: "2019-05-21 13:08:43.124354"
}
```

I want to pass into my another component and i want to store it in a variable.

Below is my code:

> services.component.html

```
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['sid','vid','serviceName','createdOn']"></tr>
            <tr class="rowhover" (click)="displayData(row,row.sid)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['sid','vid','serviceName','createdOn']"></tr>
            </table>
```

> services.component.ts

```
displayData(row,sid)
  {
    console.log(row);    
   this.router.navigate(["/vendor-list/vendor/a/services/a/details/",sid]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer after research:

1) first we have to create variable like "dataRow" in service.
2) In our parent component

```
displayData(row,sid:any)
  {
   // console.log(row);    
    this.apiService.dataRow=row;
   this.router.navigate(["/vendor-list/vendor/a/services/a/details/",sid]);
  }
```

3) in child component

```
dataRow1:any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataRow1=this.apiService.dataRow;
    console.log(this.dataRow1.serviceName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to solve your issue, I'd say use service is a good way to work it out.
Please take a look here https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

To store data:
in global scope create a variable like => data: string;
and when you get data then type => this.data = api.data, data will store in the component
To use the data across all components, you would save it in service.